# What happened in 1893?

Tags: jodatime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Odd results in Joda DateTime for 01.04.1893](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420527/odd-results-in-joda-datetime-for-01-04-1893)

I am a bit puzzled by this. What does the offset 53:28 for this date and older mean ?

```
 DateTime epoch = new DateTime(0L);
 System.out.println(epoch.minusYears(76).minusMonths(9));
 System.out.println(epoch.minusYears(76).minusMonths(10));

 1893-04-01T01:00:00.000+01:00
 1893-03-01T01:00:00.000+00:53:28
```

Comment: i guess that scientists fixx the clock because it's offset for about 6secs each year: Plus 6hours but they add a day for that each 4 years...

Comment: As I can only guess where you are located there's no way to be sure, but could it be related to [this law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railway_time#Germany)?

Comment: As I understand, Java DateTime can only hold date side January 1st of 1970, any date previous to it is not assured

Comment: See this [related Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420527/odd-results-in-joda-datetime-for-01-04-1893)